# Raw Query TO Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel

DB::select("SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians($lng) ) + sin( radians($lat) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) )) AS distance FROM salons HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 3");

this is my query which give me nearest ares according to lot and lng
I want syntax in laravel

Comment: this should not go on Code Review. this is off topic there, @Indra

Comment: @Malachi then where? This is something you can solve just by looking at the manual. It's not something that belongs on stack overflow, but it's a bit of a code review request. Please advise

Comment: this is not a Request to review the code, this is a "GIMME TEH CODEZ" question, which is off-topic anywhere on Stack Exchange

Comment: Please Refrain from suggesting sites until you know what the site is about, [Code Review Help Page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: @Malachi thanks. I guess a flag would be enough in this case then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible option with the Haversine query is using `selectRaw` and `havingRaw`.

```
$salons = Salon::select('salons.*')
        ->selectRaw('( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *
                           cos( radians( lat ) )
                           * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(?)
                           ) + sin( radians(?) ) *
                           sin( radians( lat ) ) )
                         ) AS distance', [$lat, $lng, $lat])
        ->havingRaw("distance < 25")
        ->get();
```

You can pass a specific distance by modifying the `havingRaw`:

```
->havingRaw("distance < ?", [$radius])
```

Comment: Hello. this query give me distance like this (  "distance": 0.2643362520963268, )
but i want distance like
1.2KM or  0.3KM like this

Comment: @FarhanAnees I don't understand what you mean exactly; if you want to format the result, just use `number_format()` and append the KM.